# Is there a sequence of with every other sequence as a subsequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, order-theory

Let's say we have a set $S$. Is there a sequence $u:\mathbb N \to S$ such that every other sequence $v$ is a [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of $u$?

Here is what I have so far:

If $S=\emptyset$, then no (there are no sequences to begin with).
If $|S|=1$, then yes (there is only one sequence, and every sequence is a subsequence of itself).

After these two trivial cases, I got stuck. (I expect any of these *universal* sequences to be very interesting though.) I know that the relation of subsequence is a [preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder).

For similar constructs, see [Rado graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph) or [surreal numbers](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/surreal+number).

Comment: If $S$ is finite, $S=\{s_i\}_{i=0}^{i=k-1}$ then why not take $u_i=s_{i\,mod(k)}$?  I can get any sequence as a subsequence of that.

Comment: @lulu Ah, so for for $S=\{1,2,3\}$, you would have $u=\langle 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2, \dots \rangle$. Excellent. Okay, we only have infinite $S$ left to deal with.

Comment: The posted solution, from @BenMillwood, is correct.  Indeed, I was writing a similar post when he beat me to it.

Comment: It seems to me that the digits of a normal number can form such a sequence.... Maybe that a proof con be find from the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number

Comment: @lulu: Sorry :) You can feel free to write out the proof of my claim if you like, I don't intend to bother.

Comment: @BenMillwood  Oh, no problem at all.  My (deleted) post didn't have any more detail than yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\mathbb N$, consider the sequence $0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0,1,2, 3, 4, \dots$.

I claim this sequence contains every $\mathbb N$-valued sequence as a subsequence.

This solves all countable cases. The uncountable cases are clearly impossible, since your sequence will not even cover every element, let alone every subsequence. (But if you allow uncountably long sequences, a similar trick will work.)

Comment: I feel like I've violated your expectation that the universal sequences would be very interesting, for which I apologise :P

Comment: Next I was going to ask about substrings, but then I realized that was dumb. ($\langle 1, 1, 1, 1 \rangle$ and $\langle 2, 2, 2, 2 \rangle$ have no common superstring.)

Comment: I guess one thing this leaves open is if $\aleph_0 < |S| < 2^{\aleph_1}$, but that is getting into murky territory.

Comment: @PyRulez: No, in that case $|S|$ is still uncountable (which, after all, merely means "not countable", i.e. not of cardinality $\le \aleph_0$) so your sequence still can't be surjective. Basically, if your $S$ is a surjective image of $\mathbb N$, then this trick works, whereas if it isn't, there's clearly no solution.

Comment: (Isn't $\langle 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2 \rangle$ a common superstring of your strings? Or do I misunderstand what you mean by "substring" or "superstring" or indeed "string"?)

Comment: whoops, then where supposed to be infinite.

Comment: Oh, right. Yes, in that case I agree you can't do it.

Comment: So I guess all this leaves are sets $S$ such that the statement "there exists a $f$ such that $f$ is a surjective function from $\mathbb N$ to $S$" is neither true nor false (and now we are in the "intuitionistic logic" rabbit hole).